# How to use Symfony Messenger batch message processing?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

Symfony 5.4 added the ability to batch process Messenger messages, but no documentation is available.

[Symfony - Handle messages in batches](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-messenger-improvements#handle-messages-in-batches)

[GitHub PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/43354)

How to properly use the new function? Do I need to use a specific stamp when sending a message? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples.

```
$this->eventBus->dispatch(
    (new Envelope(new TaskCreatedEvent($task)))
    ->with(new AckStamp($ack))
);
```

What should the $ack variable contain? As far as I understand there should be a function. What is her role? I tried passing a static function as the $ack argument, but the handler doesn't buffer the messages, it just processes them.

Symfony has excellent documentation and it is very strange that this function is not documented.

Comment: I wrote an article about handling messages in batches with Symfony here: https://wolfgang-klinger.medium.com/how-to-handle-messages-in-batches-with-symfony-messenger-c91b5aa1c8b1 hth

Comment: @Wolfgang, Great job! Thanks a lot! Can you add an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: By the way, unfortunately this batch handler does not work as I expected. For example, if you take your project and run messenger:consume async and then import with app:import instead of the other way around, you will see that messages are processed in multiple batches (eg 3+8+4 messages). Why not 12+3? Is that how it should be? s20.directupload.net/images/220915/85dr4mgl.png